# What exactly can preventCaching do for uploadify?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, uploadify

Simple question:
**Why we need to avoid caching for uploadify swf file?**

Recently play a lot with uploadify and the flash free version is great except the loading speed of it, as my page got couple different uploadify instances and the initialize for each of those become slower, and then I realized that the default value of setting **preventCaching** for uploadify was set to true so that it can generate random string when loading the flash. So I'm trying to see if I can turn that function off.

However the document itself does not mentioned anything why this needed, and I did Google a lot but no luck to find anything about it. People seems just leave with the default value there forever without changing it.

I tried play around with set it to **false** so that the browser can load the flash from cache and currently I can't see any differences, but I just worried about what if some browser may have some issue with it that I may not aware, we have limited QA resources so can't go through every browser to test it so wondering does anyone met any issue with set **preventCaching** to **false**

Anyone related experience? Open to any comment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question but I've spent too much time messing around with uploadify. In the end, I ditched it and switched to [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), which seems much better

Just take a look at their official forums. It's a spam house. The moderators didn't watch it. This project is a dead horse ...